# How to read a text file into a list with Python

Tags: python-3.x

How to read a text file into a list with Python

```
"Zhang Ziyi  5"
"Phteven Tuna  4"
"Drew Barrymore  3"
"Aaron Eckhart  1"
```

i try to make it in to a two list

```
name = []
scores = []
```

how can i do that??

Comment: Read answers to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split`.

**Ex:**

```
name = []
scores = []
with open("filename.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:    #Iterate each line
        *name_val, score_val = line.strip().split()   #split by space
         name.append(" ".join(name_val))      Append name
         scores.appendint(int(score_val))     Append score
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code:

```
name=[]
scores=[]
with open("text.txt",'rb+') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
lines=[d.rstrip('\n') for d in data]
for line in lines:
    name.append(line.split()[0])
    scores.append(line.split()[1])
print(name,scores)
```